# How to extract text and validate a notification message in protractor?

Tags: async-await, protractor

Problem: I would like to extract text from an element and would like to use that text to append in a validation message. How do i achieve that?

What i tried so far?

My validation message has an unique ID appended to the message. For example ( 'Story ID: 123 has been Created'). So, i would like to get the story id and then append it to my validation message.

Please find the below code snippets:

1. Locator to get the text:

   `element(by.css('.story-id'))`
2. Method which is used to assert the validation message( From Card PO):

```
async validateMessage(message) {
  await expect(element(by.css('.ng-star-inserted')).getText()).toEqual(message);
}
```

Here, message would contain something like 'Story ID has been created'.

My spec file will have something like this,
await card.validateMessage('Story ID has been created') where Story ID changes everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need to pass the message as a parameter if you know how it should look like...But in case your message is changing (but it always contains story id) you can write a couple of different expects to test each message.
Something like this:

```
async validateSuccessMessage(id) {
        let messageElement = element(element(by.cssContainingText(".story-id", id)))
        let messageText = await messageElement.getText()
        expect(await messageText).toMatch(`Story ID: ${id} has been Created`)
    }
```

and

```
async validateFailMessage(id) {
        let messageElement = element(element(by.cssContainingText(".story-id", id)))
        let messageText = await messageElement.getText()
        expect(await messageText).toMatch(`Oops! Story ID: ${id} was not created`)
    }
```

p.s. If cssContainingText does not work use Xpath (you did not include the HTML so I'm guessing here).

Sorry in advance if I got your idea wrong

Comment: Thanks for the answer and really appreciate your effort in assisting me on this!

Answer (score 1):

1. `expect()` doesn't need `await` before it. But I did see it fail when you don't pass it to the parameter it takes. So it should be `expect(await element.getText()).toBe("string")`
2. Don't wrap expect to a function! Why? Because if it fails it'll point to the line number where if failed and ease the process of debugging. Just as a best practice
3. If you want to extract just the number from a string `'Story ID: 123 has been Created'` use regex

```
let str =  'Story ID: 123 has been Created',
    regex = /(Story ID:\s+)(\d+)/;

let result = str.match(regex);

console.log(result[2]); // 123 or any other integer that is there
```

I didn't get your question 100%, but I think you can take from here

Comment: Thanks for the answer and really appreciate your effort in assisting me on this!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for suggestions and ideas. I was able the achieve with the below code snippet. Apologize if my question wasn't clear, but couple of answers were truly helpful in achieving the below.

```
   /* Store the story id in messageText variable */     

            const messageElement = element(by.css('.story-id');
            const messageText = messageElement.getText();

            /* Since messageText returns a promise, i'm printing it to 'message' variable */

messageText.then(async function(message) {
            console.log(message)
            /* Verifying the text from message with actual text */
            await expect(element(by.css('.ng-star-inserted').getText()).toEqual('"'+message+' sucessfully deleted.');

            })

        }
```